# My condition checking is not properly work in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show an alert message when the check box is not selected. I use the following code for that purpose

```
function IsEmpty(){
        var oldpath = document.forms['pathuploader'].oldpath.value;
        var newpath = document.forms['pathuploader'].newpath.value;
        var metavalue = !document.forms['pathuploader'].chkmeta.checked;
        var postvalue = !document.forms['pathuploader'].chkpost.checked;
      if((oldpath == "")||((oldpath.substring(0,4))!='http')||((oldpath.substring(0,4))=='Http'))
        {
            alert("Enter a valid URL");
            return false;

        }
        if((newpath == "")||(newpath.substring(0,4)!='http')||(newath.substring(0,4)!='Http'))
        {
            alert("Enter a valid URL");
            return false;

        }
        if((metavalue) && (postvalue))
        {
            alert("Select any category to change");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem PHP relevant... is there more to this?

Comment: What is happening when you run this code? Also, try to abstract only the portion not working, and also post that code result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6jpmwwff/)

First of all you have a typo on the following line

```
if((newpath == "")||(newpath.substring(0,4)!='http')||(newath.substring(0,4)!='Http'))
```

> The last if is "newath" should be "newpath" and the same area "!=" should match the oldpath logic and instead be "==".

To clean up the code just a bit more, use "===" and "!==" instead of just "==" as this forces a more precise comparison.

See this link for more info [use strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)

Here is adjusted code

Also, try to use a camelCase naming convention if you wish to comply with JS standards. I have corrected the "IsEmpty" function to be "isEmpty" as an example.

```
function isEmpty(){
   var oldpath = document.forms['pathuploader'].oldpath.value;
   var newpath = document.forms['pathuploader'].newpath.value;
   var metavalue = !document.forms['pathuploader'].chkmeta.checked;
   var postvalue = !document.forms['pathuploader'].chkpost.checked;
  if((oldpath === "")||((oldpath.substring(0,4))!=='http')||((oldpath.substring(0,4))==='Http'))
   {
    alert("Enter a valid old URL");
    return false;

   }
  if((newpath === "")||(newpath.substring(0,4)!=='http')||(newpath.substring(0,4)==='Http')){
    alert("Enter a valid new URL");
    return false;
  }
  if((metavalue) && (postvalue)){
    alert("Select any category to change");
    return false;
  }
  return true;
```

}

**UPDATE** I also agree with "Sourabh" where the BANG (!) should be. As in

```
if(( !metavalue ) && ( !postvalue ){
```

instead of how it is currently. Both work, but the BANG is hiding in the variable. If you did keep it where it is, perhaps you could alert the next programmer that may view your code by calling it

```
var metaValueNotChecked = !document.forms...
var postValueNotChecked = !document.forms...
```

Then it would read correctly as

```
if(( metaValueNotChecked ) && ( postValueNotChecked ){
```

In this case, the BANG should be where you have it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Whats the difference between oldpath == "" and oldpath === ""?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators

Answer (score 0):

use the below procedure for more better way to do it, i am assuming that you have elements defined in your form, you need to change this two parts of code

first:

```
var metavalue = document.forms['pathuploader'].chkmeta.checked;
var postvalue = document.forms['pathuploader'].chkpost.checked;
```

then in if condition use the below procedure:

```
if(!metavalue && !postvalue)
        {
            alert("Select any category to change");
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Although I agree with your point about code structure, there shouldn't be any difference between this way and the original similar portion regarding code execution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "required" from HTML5, and remove it once a checkbox is checked, from every other of your checkbox. ex:

```
<input required="required" value="1" name="site[source][]" id="site_source_any" type="checkbox">

<input required="required" value="2" name="site[source][]" id="site_source_many" type="checkbox">
```

In your script file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        // Check if atleast one of the checkbox is checked
        $(function(){
          var requiredCheckboxes = $(':checkbox[required]');
          requiredCheckboxes.change(function(){
          if(requiredCheckboxes.is(':checked')) {
        // Remove Required once at-least one is checked
          requiredCheckboxes.removeAttr('required');
          }
          else {
            requiredCheckboxes.attr('required', 'required');
           }
         });
       });

        </script>
```